# Scala polymorphic method (or higher kind??)

Tags: scala

I want to define a compression method that compresses a collection of a certain type `Int` or `String` into a string. I wanted to combine the two methods that I currently have:

```
  def compressString[T <: IndexedSeq[String]]: (T) => 
                        String = (array: T) => array.mkString(" ")
  def compressInt[T <: IndexedSeq[Int]]: (T) => 
                        String = (array: T) => array.mkString(" ")
```

Into one method. I tried to do higher kinded type with `T[Int]` but it didn't work that way. I also tried to do:

```
   def compress[U, T <: IndexedSeq[U]]: (T) => String = 
                         (array: T) => array.mkString(" ")
```

However, the compiler gives me this error:

```
[error] type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Iterator[Int(in method compress)]
[error]  required: Iterator[scala.Int]
[error]     collect(array.iterator, Vector.empty[String], 0).mkString("\t")
[error]                   ^
[error] SVM.scala:55: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : java.lang.String
[error]  required: String(in method compress)
[error]   override def compress[String, T <: IndexedSeq[String]]: (T) => String = (array: T) => array.mkString("\t")
```

In general, I want to eventually override this method and provide concrete implementation (the method that deals with `Int` is different from `String`). How do I combine these two methods??

Comment: `Int(in method compress)` usually means you've instanciated a new generic with the name `Int`.

Comment: You just want a version of `compress` that operates on any `IndexedSeq[_]` reguardless of the type in the seq, right?

Comment: @isomarcte yes, but I want to mark the type as well because I want to be able to provide different methods for different class inside. Like if the underlying type is `String` I do something, and if the underlying type is `Int`, I do something else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make your generic method compile, you need to pass the first type argument as the type of IndexedSeq, i.e.

```
def compress[U, T <: IndexedSeq[U]]: (T) => String = {
  (array: T) => array.mkString(" ")
}

then you can invoke it like,
val strings = compress[String,Vector[String]](Vector("a","b")) // strings: String = a b
val ints = compress[Int,Vector[Int]](Vector(1,2)) // ints: String = 1 2
```

However, I think a [type class](https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html) would fit much better in the case that you want to have ad hoc polymorphism.

For example, you can define the following type class:

```
@implicitNotFound("No compressor found for type ${T}")
trait Compressor[T] {
  def compress(array: IndexedSeq[T]): String
}
```

and create an implementation for every type that you want to support compression

```
implicit val stringCompressor = new Compressor[String] {
  override def compress(array: IndexedSeq[String]): String = array.mkString(" ")
}

implicit val intCompressor = new Compressor[Int] {
  override def compress(array: IndexedSeq[Int]): String = array.mkString(" ")
}
```

then you can call the methods directly

```
val strings = stringCompressor.compress(Vector("a","b"))  // strings: String = a b
val ints = intCompressor.compress(Vector(1,2)) // ints: String = 1 2
```

or you can define a generic method that takes an implicit parameter

```
def compress[T](array: IndexedSeq[T])(implicit compressor: Compressor[T]): String = {
  compressor.compress(array)
}

// or equivalently
def compress[T: Compressor](array: IndexedSeq[T]): String = {
  implicitly[Compressor[T]].compress(array)
}
```

and use like this

```
val strings = compress(Vector("a","b"))  // strings: String = a b
val ints = compress(Vector(1,2))         // ints: String = 1 2
```

if there is no implicit compressor defined in the scope, the compiler will give you an error, e.g.

```
compress(Vector(true, false))
error: No compressor found for type Boolean
          compress(Vector(true, false))
                  ^
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I don't even know I can use keyword new on a trait!

Comment: @AllenNie Yeah, it just creates a new anonymous instance of that trait. You can do the same thing in Java for interfaces (often used for Functional Interfaces that fake having first class functions).

Comment: Your second example is exactly what I intended to do: override the original method, and provide a new special method for each type (`Int` and `String`)...but is there an easier way that I can just call `compress` instead of `compressInt` or `compressString`?

Comment: Good answer. You might add a note about the typical use of a type class in Scala for the uninitiated, i.e. `def needsCompressor[T: Compressor]...`

Comment: @AllenNie There is. The idiom that is being described above is known as "Type Classes". Typically you define your instances with the `implicit` keyword, i.e. `implicit val intCompressor`. Then you use it like so,

`def needsCompressor[T: Compressor] = {val t: Compresssor[T] = implicitly[Compressor[T]]}`

Comment: @isomarcte I've heard of Type Classes from a Haskell context but never used it. Can you please update this example to your answer so I can better understand it?? Thank you very much!

Comment: The best resource I know of is here (https://twitter.github.io/scala_school/advanced-types.html). You will notice that Twitter calls what I call a "Type Class" a "Other Type Bounds", in my experience the terms are somewhat muddled now in scala. Other documentation reverses the notation. If you want, ask another question on SO about type classes in scala (I couldn't find one that had already been asked...) and I would be happy to answer it. Just post a link to the new question here (or chat). I shouldn't answer it here as it is against SO policy(i.e. off topic for the question asked)

Comment: I have updated the answer with an example using implicits. As for "Type Classes" in Scala, I agree with @isomarcte that it is better to discuss it in a different thread. It is an interesting and potentially lengthy topic.

Comment: @isomarcte I have updated the answer with the link from your comment. Cheers.